# Android- How to skip first activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android application. In first time run, first activity will open and will save a value in the application's storage. When I reopen the application, I want to skip the first activity. How can I do that?

When reopen:

```
if(stogage_value == "enable"){
  skip first activity;
}else{
first activity;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16419627/1765530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save a Boolean flag on first launch in [sharedpreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and read this value before activity launch

now check boolean value

so your code will  be something like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ....
 Boolean flag;
loadSavedPreferences();
Intent myIntent;
if(flag){
 myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
 savePreferences()
 }else{
 myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);

private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    flag = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("FirstLaunch", true);

}

private void savePreferences() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("FirstLaunch", false);
    editor.commit();

}
  }
```

Here is video tutorial for shared preference from [slidenerd](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riyMQiHY3V4)

Answer (score 1):

After first run store flag value in shared preference.And every time check for that value if not first run call second activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent myIntent;
if(stogage_value == "enable"){
   myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
}else{
   myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
}
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use shared preferences to maintain a counter or a flag. Simply set the flag to true when activity called for first time and after that if flag is true , call another activity or do something else. Refer the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16419799/1833437).

Answer (score 1):

In OnCreate you can implement in this way.You have to save "stogage_value" in preference

```
 boolean firstTime = "";   //get this value from preference
    if(!firstTime){
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(First.this, NextActivity.class);

        firstTime = false;
      // here save this in  preference
    }else{
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply run the new activity and stop first activity

```
if(stogage_value == "enable"){
  Intent i = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
  startActivity(i); //start second activity
  finish(); //finish first activity
}else{
  //do nothing
}
```